# A function not equal to its Taylor series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have been given this problem as a practice for an upcoming exam and I am unsure how to approach it.

Give and example of a function that has derivatives of all orders, but is not equal to the sum of its Taylor series. Justify your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a non-analytic smooth function. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function